# Windows - Long freezing busy process after restart following sudden turn off

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, process, cpu-usage

I've accidentally snapped my Windows because of power issue while playing a video from a locally remote computer. After booted again it first prompted me whether I want to fix or restart. I chose to restart because it's happened multiple times before without any serious injury to the Windows.

But this time it's different. It was rebooted successfully. Suddenly after half an hour everything is freezing. At first I can still do clicking on taskbar buttons with nothing happens afterward, selecting files, and toggling windows, but not for long. When I clicked on opened window close button, the button was disabled but the "(not responding)" text didn't show up. Afterall the taskbar also frozen and busy cursor showing. The fan was spinning quite fast for a long period which means CPU is doing a hard task.

But the strange is the video was still able to continue playing. Keyboard's and mouse's buttons are not working before and after replugging them, but I can still moving the mouse around. When I CTRL+ALT+DEL for the first time, the mouse cursor was reset to the center of screen but no task manager opened, before everything was frozen completely.

After a while, the freezing ended. I was allowed to interact with Windows for a number of seconds before it was frozen again. After twice of freezing, an alert popped up with title "Microsoft Windows is not responding". I chose "End process", closing all windows and recreating the taskbar and desktop icons. Everything is fine so far but sometines the freezing happened again but not as long as the first one.

I think that sudden shutdown triggered a background service which was consuming my CPU completely and froze everything. When I checked it's also consuming the GPU since the graph was also peaking. I guess it's just a disk checking process. I've also checked the resource monitor but yet I can't tell which process had done it. How may I know it and at least trying to stop it?

Comment: Perhaps see if you can do a disk check, reboot, let it do it's thing and then maybe it might come good?

Comment: Turns out it's not the power issue my PC had but only I didn't plug the SSD properly, causing WIndows to overconsume the CPU for disk I/O job. It answers both this problem and the snap. I think it still has to do with disk checking because the freezing didn't occurs on Ubuntu